# Android NDK Build failing for simple native function

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, makefile, build-error

I am trying to build a very simple native function using ndk-build and getting the following error.

```
DriverAdapter.cpp:6:69: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'this'
```

The following are my .mk and .cpp files

DriverAdapter.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#define DEBUG_TAG "NDK_AndroidNDK1SampleActivity"

void Java_com_ihearhtpi_MainActivity_helloLog(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jstring logThis)
{
   jboolean isCopy;
    const char * szLogThis = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, logThis, &isCopy);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", szLogThis);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, logThis, szLogThis);
}
```

Android.mk

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

```
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    :=driver
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=DriverAdapter.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is c++ keyword. And you can't use a keyword as variable name.

Comment: The following alternatives are commonly used: thiz, self, me, _pThis... Pick one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't name your argument "this"